# Extract strings before and after the occurance of a key string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string like

```
$script = "mycommand param1=arnab user=user1 mapping=arn1:schema1,arn2:schema2"
```

I want to extract everything before `mapping=` and also everything after it in two variables.

To extract everything before `mapping=` I tried:

```
$script_piece1 = $script =~ m/(.*)mapping=/;
```

However I am getting syntax error at this line.

How to do this correctly?

Comment: That line doesn't have a syntax error

Comment: @Arnab i think you get the syntax error from line number 1. Because you missed the semi colon.

Comment: Oh Yes, The syntax error was in a earlier line because I had a extra ")". But the $script_piece1 is coming as null unlike you said in your answer below. Anyways I am trying out your solution and will post back here soon

Comment: @Arnab: Those two statements result in `$script_piece1` being set to 1. You real code must be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is perfectly valid, but it will set `$script_piece1` to a *true* or *false* value according to whether `$script` contains the string `mapping=`

You need to put the regex test in *list context* to get it to return the contents of any *captures* in the pattern, and you may as well grab both parts at once like this

```
my ($piece1, $piece2) = $script =~ /(.*?)mapping=(.*)/;
```

But it's neater as a `split`, like this

```
my ($piece1, $piece2) = split /mapping=/, $script, 2;
```

Comment: Just for the future readers , the  <   /(.*?)mapping=(.*)/;    > above should be < m/(.*?)mapping=(.*)/;    >

Comment: @Arnab: No, it shouldn't. The `m` is optional and is usually omitted